# Show progressbar in actionbar from fragment is not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar, navigation-drawer

I have an android app with navigation drawer. So I have only one activity and many fragments, at least one for every menu item. My problem is that I can't get the progressbar in the actionbar to show without having to specify a progressbar in a specific menu for each fragment (assuming you want to have different action bar items depending on which fragment you're showing you're ending up with specifying a lot of menues).

Isn't there a way to have a global menu, common for all, and then just add the menu items I want for each fragment?

In my MainActivity I have:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And in the fragments I have:

```
getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

and

```
getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

The menu looks like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_progress"
    android:title="Loading..."
    android:visible="false"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/progressbar_layout" />
```

Edit:

I have a MVP model so I'm calling showProgress like this:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment implements DashboardView {

private DashboardPresenterImpl presenter;
private RelativeLayout incidentsContainer;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    incidentsContainer = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.incidentsContainer);
    toggleView(View.GONE);

    presenter = new DashboardPresenterImpl(this);

    try {
        presenter.loadIncidents();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void toggleView(int visibility) {
    incidentsContainer.setVisibility(visibility);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    setTitle(R.string.dashboard);
}

@Override
public void showProgress() {
    getActivity().getActionBar();
    getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
}

@Override
public void hideProgress() {
    getActivity().getActionBar();
    getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}

@Override
public void showContent() {
    toggleView(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

And the Presenter, which is calling showProgress() looks like this:

```
public class DashboardPresenterImpl implements DashboardPresenter {

    private DashboardView view;

    public DashboardPresenterImpl(DashboardView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void loadIncidents() throws InterruptedException {
        view.showProgress();
        new LoadContentTask().execute();
    }

    private class LoadContentTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return 0l;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            view.showContent();
            view.hideProgress();
        }
    }
}
```

The async task is now just to fake some loading of data and test the progress bar.

These are the two global menu items I want to be available for every menu item. But the progressbar is not showing and hiding on command from the fragment. So what am I missing here?

Comment: show how you are callling `getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` in fragments

Comment: `showProgress` printing in log ?

Comment: what is `DashboardView` ?

Comment: It's the view, in the MVP model, i.e. an interface for the view logic:
public interface DashboardView {
    void showProgress();
    void hideProgress();
    void showContent();
}

Comment: And to be clear, the fragments extends Fragment.

Comment: dont show/hide from interface, try to do it directly.

Comment: I didn't make a difference. And why would it? The content of showProgress is still in the fragment and it's being called.

Comment: I was thinking if somehow ref is not getting passed.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the support library and support fragment? In which case you would need to call the support versions of the above methods.

Comment: I've tried: ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

But it makes no difference.